# renamed xml file isn't declared in R.java

Tags: android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

i am customizing an action bar, and i am using inflater and styles.

i added a `menu.xml` to a menu folder in project which i inflated into the onOptionsMenu,
the menu.xml contains the action bar item's.

Everything worked fine, until i `renamed menu.xml` to `actionBar_menu.xml`using refractor.

Now i can't even add it to the Inflater. it's not even declared in R.java

How do i solve the problem any hint or solution?

Thank you

Edit:

Thank you guys for your answers.

i did what you asked so i changed my action bar to actionb_menu.xml, but it still not working.

otherwise it's now declared in R.java, but eclipse editor doesn't recognize it 
(ctrl+space), and even if i ignore this and continue typing the name of the file in the inflater it it still underlined as an error.

any solution for that??

Comment: clean and build your project and reRun...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original problem was: *You can only use lowercase letters, numbers and underscores in your layout XML file name.* As stated by @midoalageb

**This is the answer to your edit**.

Because your id wasn't initially in your R.java when you tried to do

```
 R.id.....
```

eclipse has imported `android.R;` into your class file.

You need to go up to the top of your file delete this import:

```
 import android.R;
```

then attempt to do:

```
 R.id.whatever
```

again. When you press ctrl+space after `R.` ensure you select `com.your.package.R` and not `android.R`

Answer (score 1):

hey hosni habeby look do like this,
open your new xml file the one you re named it and go to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.something. app.OldJava" />
```

and replace the context value to your new java file the one you renamed also.. like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.something. app.MyNewActivityJava" />
```

in eclipse when you changed java file's name and it xml.. eclipse will not touch the values in the xml so we have to change it our selves also eclipse will add an import line may not refer to your R file.. if so remove it and type one that refers to your R file of your project not of Android or any library

Answer (score 0):

You can only use lowercase letters, numbers and underscores in your layout XML file name. So rename your file to `actionbar_menu.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Project. Refresh it first--> then clean it --> then rebuild it -->if there are necessary code changes then do it--> it should work.

also rename it in all small case chars

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project. If it still says R cannot be resolved then there should be something wrong with the xml file. Check your xml file for some extra characters that you mistyped or something of that kind. Your R file will not be built if even one xml file has an error!